# Help with extruding evenly around a cylinder

Tags: modeling

I'm having some issues trying to extrude faces around a cylinder to create this collar for car suspension.  I was wondering if anybody had tips on getting this shape made.  I've tried a few iterations now but just circular shapes are just the bane of my existence.  Would appreciate any input/help!

[image: this is where i'm currently at]

[image: trying to create the shapes boxed in red]

Comment: If the first screenshot is from your work: I'm not sure I'm seeing a specific issue to solve.   Can you edit your question and also perhaps mark up the screenshot to explain your challenge?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue.  Instead of deleting the faces on the bottom of the extrude, I used LoopTools > Circle to after extruding to maintain the shape, then deleting the faces after I finished extruding the circles.  Boolean would have made things a lot easier, but this was good practice extruding without boolean.  Came out exactly how I wanted while maintaining pretty clean toplogy.

[image]